# How in Java do I create an associative array structure and sorted, while keeping duplicate keys with different values pairs

Tags: java, associative-array, java-6

Two comma separated strings exist.

The first string is essentially the keys and the second is the linked values,

The first string needs to be in ascending order while retaining any duplicate values, and the second string needs to follow in suit to maintain the sequence as such.

Looked at hashmaps and tuples without success so far. 
System is Java 6

```
String A = "3, 4, 1, 2, 3"
String B = "19, 24, 32, 68, 50"
```

Result Output needed

```
String A = "1, 2, 3, 3, 4"
String B = "32, 68, 19, 50, 24"
```

Comment: make a `Pair` class to contain your values, split the strings and put values from each resulting array in a list of `Pair`s, sort by first element of pair, re-join to get string. If there's something in particular you need help with after reading this *and* trying to implement it, ask again no problem.

Comment: If you want to use a `Map`, you have to use one that holds a `List` as its value because you can only map a single value to a single key.

Comment: @deHaar not really. The first string is meant to be used as a set of keys and the second one as a set of values so that there's a one-to-one correspondence between the two. No lists need to be involved.

Comment: @FedericoklezCulloca I think you're right, but for the sake of completeness, I have provided both possibilities in my answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a multitude of possibilities to realize your requirements. Here are two examples (existing in parallel within the example code):

1. You can use a `Map<Integer, List<Integer>>` that holds a key and all values it has in a `List`
2. you can create a POJO class that holds exactly one key and one value, but you need to make it sortable/comparable and use a suitable data structure

See this example and pay attention to the code comments:

```
public class StackoverflowMain {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String a = "3, 4, 1, 2, 3";
        String b = "19, 24, 32, 68, 50";

        // Map-approach: use a map that maps a key to a list of values
        Map<Integer, List<Integer>> ab = new TreeMap<>();
        // Pair-approach: make a sortable POJO that holds a key and a value only
        // and create a data structure that holds them sorted
        SortedSet<Pair> pairList = new TreeSet<Pair>();

        // split both Strings by comma
        String[] aSplit = a.split(",");
        String[] bSplit = b.split(",");

        // check if the length of the resulting arrays is the same
        if (aSplit.length == bSplit.length) {
            // if yes, go through the arrays of numbers
            for (int i = 0; i < aSplit.length; i++) {
                int key = Integer.parseInt(aSplit[i].trim());
                int value = Integer.parseInt(bSplit[i].trim());

                // in the Pair-approach, you just have to create a Pair with the value found
                Pair pair = new Pair(key, value);
                // and add it to the set of pairs
                pairList.add(pair);

                // the following check is only needed for the Map-solution
                if (ab.containsKey(key)) {
                    // if the key is already present,
                    // just add the new value to its value list
                    ab.get(key).add(value);
                    // sort the value list each time a new value has been added
                    ab.get(key).sort(Comparator.naturalOrder());
                } else {
                    // if the key is not present in the Map so far,
                    // create a new List for the value
                    List<Integer> valueList = new ArrayList<>();
                    // add the value to that list
                    valueList.add(value);
                    // and put both into the Map
                    ab.put(key, valueList);
                }
            }
        } else {
            System.err.println("The Strings have different amounts of elements!");
        }

        // print what's in the Map
        System.out.println("Map-approach:");
        for (int key : ab.keySet()) {
            List<Integer> value = ab.get(key);
            for (int val : value) {
                System.out.println(key + " : " + val);
            }
        }

        System.out.println("————————————————");

        System.out.println("Pairs-approach:");
        for (Pair pair : pairList) {
            System.out.println(pair.key + " : " + pair.val);
        }
    }

    /**
     * This class is needed for the Pair-approach.
     * It is comparable (and by that, sortable) and will be sorted by key
     * and if the keys are equal, it will sort by value.
     */
    static class Pair implements Comparable<Pair> {
        int key;
        int val;

        Pair(int key, int value) {
            this.key = key;
            this.val = value;
        }

        @Override
        public int compareTo(Pair otherPair) {
            if (key == otherPair.key) {
                if (val == otherPair.val) {
                    return 0;
                } else if (val < otherPair.key) {
                    return -1;
                } else {
                    return 1;
                }
            } else if (key < otherPair.key) {
                return -1;
            } else {
                return 1;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This code produces the following output:

```
Map-approach:
1 : [32]
2 : [68]
3 : [19, 50]
4 : [24]
————————————————
Pairs-approach:
1 : 32
2 : 68
3 : 19
3 : 50
4 : 24
```

**EDIT**

Since the `Pair`-approach does not sort correctly, I came up with this `Map`-approach:

```
public class StackoverflowMain {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String a = "3, 4, 1, 3, 3, 2, 3";
        String b = "5, 24, 35, 99, 32, 68, 19";

        // Map-approach: use a map that maps a key to a list of values
        Map<Integer, List<Integer>> ab = new TreeMap<>();

        // split both Strings by comma
        String[] aSplit = a.split(",");
        String[] bSplit = b.split(",");

        // check if the length of the resulting arrays is the same
        if (aSplit.length == bSplit.length) {
            // if yes, go through the arrays of numbers
            for (int i = 0; i < aSplit.length; i++) {
                int key = Integer.parseInt(aSplit[i].trim());
                int value = Integer.parseInt(bSplit[i].trim());

                // the following check is only needed for the Map-solution
                if (ab.containsKey(key)) {
                    // if the key is already present, just add the new value to its value list
                    ab.get(key).add(value);
                    // sort the value list each time a new value has been added
                    ab.get(key).sort(Comparator.naturalOrder());
                } else {
                    // if the key is not present in the Map so far, create a new List for the value
                    List<Integer> valueList = new ArrayList<>();
                    // add the value to that list
                    valueList.add(value);
                    // and put both into the Map
                    ab.put(key, valueList);
                }
            }
        } else {
            System.err.println("The Strings have different amounts of elements!");
        }

        // print what's in the Map
        System.out.println("Map-approach:");
        for (int key : ab.keySet()) {
            List<Integer> value = ab.get(key);
            for (int val : value) {
                System.out.println(key + " : " + val);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

It is shorter and uses a `Map<Integer, List<Integer>>` and sorts the `List<Integer>` every time a new value gets added (apart from the first value, which doesn't need a sort). That needed another loop in the output code, but you don't have to create a new class.

It produces the following output:

```
Map-approach:
1 : 35
2 : 68
3 : 5
3 : 19
3 : 32
3 : 99
4 : 24
```

Comment: If that result then needed sorted e.g. desc so the keys 3=>19, 3=>50 become reordered to 3=>50, 3=>19 what would the best way to do it be? @deHaar

Comment: @TrevorClarke The best way (in my opinion) would be to adjust the method `compareTo` of the class `Pair`. This would just mean to swap the return statements for the cases `val < otherPair.key` and `val > otherPair.key`, which is the `else` block. Take the `Pairs`-approach and return `1` if the value is **less than** the one of the other pair and return `-1` if it is greater. In my answer, it is the other way round. That is the way to change the sorting direction.

Comment: I gave that a try and seemed to work until I extended the dataset:
`code`     String a = "3, 4, 1, 3, 3, 2, 3";
        String b = "5, 24, 35, 99, 32, 68, 19";

Pairs-approach:
1 : 35
2 : 68
3 : 19
3 : 32
3 : 99
3 : 5
4 : 24 `code`

Comment: @TrevorClarke That's weird... I will take a look.

Comment: ideally it should end up
3 : 5
3 : 19
3 : 32
3 : 99

Comment: @TrevorClarke I have decided to use the `Map`-approach and just sort the value list. Have a look at my edit.

Answer (score 0):

First: java 6 is too old; at least java 8 (generic types, expressive Streams). Then use variable & method names starting with a small letter, as this is a really hard community convention.

In java 6 a *poor* solution would be an array of packed longs:

- Sorting must be done on pairs of A and B values, so here the values are packied.
- Wanting things ordered implies a logarithmic access time for a get,
  hence a binary search on a sorted array is feasible.
- The consequence of using arrays is the fixed array size: insert/delete being cumbersome;
  a List would be better, a Map then best.

Turn the strings into data of single elements.

```
public class MapIntToInts {
    long[] ab;

    public MapIntToInts (String A, String B) {
        String[] a = A.split(", ");
        String[] b = B.split(", ");

        ab = new int[a.length];
        for (int i = 0; i < ab.length; ++i) {
            long key = Integer.parseInt(a[i]) << 32L;
            long value = Integer.parseInt(b[i]) && 0xFFFF_FFFFL;
            ab[i] = key | value;
        }
        Arrays.sort(ab);
    }
```

Getting the values of one A key can be done by a binary search in **O(log N)** time:

```
    public int[] get(int key) {
        long abKey <<= 32L;
        int firstI = Arrays.binSearch(ab, key);
        if (firstI < 0) { // Not found
            firstI = ~firstI ; // Insert position
        }
        int i = firstI;
        while (i < ab.length && ab[i] >> 32 == key) {
            ++i;
        }
        int n = i - firstI;
        int[] result = new int[n];
        for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
            result[i] = (int)ab[firstI + i];
        }
        Arrays.sort(result); // For mixed negative positive values
        return result();
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
String A = "3, 4, 1, 2, 3";
String B = "19, 24, 32, 68, 50";

MapIntToInts map = MapIntToInts(A, B);
int[] results = map.get(3);
```

Improvements:

- Replace `long[] ab;` by `int[] a; int[b];` or better:
- Replace `long[] ab;` by `int[] uniqueKeys; int[][] values;`.

Comment: Old complex legacy system running Java 6 so that is just how it is.

Comment: @TrevorClarke I was afraid of that. Map from Integer to List of Integer might be more versatile.

Answer (score 0):

You should invest more into decomposing a problem into smaller chunks. For example, converting a string into array of integers is a far more simple operation than the one declared in the title. Let's assume it could be dealt with separately.

```
Integer[] A = {3, 4, 1, 2, 3};
Integer[] B = {19, 24, 32, 68, 50};
```

So, when you have two integer arrays at your disposal, you can benefit from *natural ordering*—it will allow you to skip `Comparator` implementation should you choose a `SortedMap` solution.

```
SortedMap<Integer, List<Integer>> map = new TreeMap<Integer, List<Integer>>();

for (int i = 0; i < A.length; i++) {
  if (map.get(A[i]) == null) {
    List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    list.add(B[i]);
    map.put(A[i], list);
  } else {
    map.get(A[i]).add(B[i]);
  }
}
```

With the above mentioned the most complex thing to do will be getting rid of the trailing comma when creating an output. But with a small trick it shouldn't be a problem.

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
for (List<Integer> list : map.values()) {
  for (Integer integer : list) {
    sb.append(", ").append(integer);
  }
}

String output = sb.toString().substring(2);
```

If you want to verify the answer, you can enable assertions by passing *-ea* argument to JVM on application start (or just write a unit test).

```
assert output.equals("32, 68, 19, 50, 24");
```